# Do Android Wearables support text-to-speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, wear-os

I am trying to follow this tutorial for my Android wearables app:

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-android-text-to-speech-to-create-a-smart-assistant/

Here is the code for my Activity file:

```
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

public class ScoresActivity extends Activity {
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores);

        // Text to speech setup
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                System.out.println("status: " + status);    // Always returns -1

                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
                    }

                    speak("Hello");

                } else {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I always see this error message in the Logs:
[image]

Is it even possible to run the Android SDK's text-to-speech library on wearable devices? I tried running this code on a mobile Android app and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depends which device you have. I think it needs to have android wear 2.0 and then possibly a speaker would make it more likely. Im only saying that based on knowing my nixon mission does not have tts installed but the lg urbane 2 does. Very annoying as tts could be used over bluetooth.

Would be good to get a full listed of supported devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible as they even have docs for this feauture in [Adding Voice Capabilities](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html):

Voice actions are an important part of the wearable experience. They let users carry out actions hands-free and quickly. Wear provides two types of voice actions:

> **System-provided** These voice actions are task-based and are built into the Wear platform. You filter for them in the activity that you
>   want to start when the voice action is spoken. Examples include "Take
>   a note" or "Set an alarm".
>
> **App-provided** These voice actions are app-based, and you declare them just like a launcher icon. Users say "Start " to use these voice
>   actions and an activity that you specify starts.

You can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788695/running-android-text-to-speech-on-android-wear) for additional reference.

Comment: voice capabilities is not text to speech, kind of the opposite.